# Image zoom Volley NetworkImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to zoom the image but I am not able to get, I am getting image url link in `i.getStringExtra("image");`....what should I do ?this code is successfully displaying the image but no zoom in/out working in image..

1.)**SingleItemView.java**

```
public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        private static String TAG;
        ImageView_Main itemImage;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            // Get the view from singlelistview.xml
            setContentView(R.layout.singlelistview);

            try {
                Intent i = getIntent();
                String image = i.getStringExtra("image");

                // Zoom the image
                NetworkImageView itemImage = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
                itemImage.setImageUrl(image, imageLoader);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

2.)**singlelistview.xml**

```
 <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
                    android:id="@+id/itemImage"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="370dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/g"
                    android:background="@drawable/border"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/geeknizer/Volley-Flickr-Gson-List-GridView-example/blob/master/src/com/androidng/flickr/view/NetworkImageView.java) to achive zoom. This has many helper functions to achieve what you need.

Comment: i am not able to do it could you please help ?